# Quarkus ,How to send Mqtt Messages with retain flag?

Tags: java, mqtt, publish-subscribe, quarkus, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I'm currently sending Mqtt Messages with Quarkus using smallrye reactive messsaging,the problem is when i add retain flag to true,nothing change.

Here is how i do it:

```
    @Broadcast
    @Channel("myChannel")
    Emitter<MyObject> emitter;
```

```
emitter.send(MqttMessage.of("/mytopic",data,MqttQoS.EXACTLY_ONCE,true));
```

any help or guidance will be appreciated

Comment: I assume you meant to include a closing quote after the topic? Note that the leading slash can lead to confusion (this effectively introduces a [zero byte topic level](https://www.hivemq.com/blog/mqtt-essentials-part-5-mqtt-topics-best-practices/#best-practices)). When you say "nothing change" what do you mean (are you looking at the broker logs, reconnecting and not receiving the retained message etc?).

Comment: Edit the question to show how you are testing for a retained message.

Comment: Thank you for your replies, to be more clear, I mean when I'm resubscribing to the same topic (In the frontEnd),I don't receive the retained messages. also I test through  using an MQTT client for windows also some Google Chrome extensions,

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try using io.smallrye.reactive.messaging.mqtt.SendingMqttMessage to build your message.